# Why Laravel Resource Create and Edit operations are depicted using GET

Tags: laravel

I am picking up on Laravel, and noted that on [Laravel's Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers), it states that the the GET HTTP verb will be handled by the create and edit operations, but from my understanding of [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete), a create or edit operation actually results in change of records or state on the back-end. So why does Laravel choose to use GET for create and edit operations?

Comment: The `create` and `edit` URLs use `GET` for showing the forms to create/edit a resource, but saving (changing the records), is handled in the `store` and `update` commands, which use `POST` and `PUT/PATCH`.

Comment: @KirkBeard So the verbs are specifically for showing what's happening on the UI and not at the back-end?

Comment: When you load `https://example.com/resource/create`, that does not change records on on the backed, so it's perfectly acceptable for it to use `GET`. That page would contain `<form method="POST" action="https://example.com/resource/store">` which would process the `$_POST` data, and modify the records in your database (or wherever they may be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Laravel `creat and edit` method uses `GET` request because they are used to render a view where you can add or update your data. When you submit you form it will use `store and update` method which are `POST and PUT/PATCH` request to save the data into database.